# Why is clock cycle time the inverse of clock rate?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-speed

Im studying computer performance and I cant understand why

clock cycle time = 1 / clock rate

Why is this obvious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clock rate is usually expressed in herts (Hz).

1 Hz = 1 cycle/second.

It's just simple mathematics. To get how much seconds it takes for 1 cycle, then you just have to invert it.